# Rails calculate the difference between two datetimes in seconds and converting to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, integer, coercion

I am trying to set :total_time to the difference between 2 datetime items (:start_time and :end_time) in seconds. I can get the value that I want in the view by doing the following

```
<%= (@result.end_time.minus_with_coercion(@result.start_time)).round %>
```

but now I need to populate :total_time with this value when creating @result in the controller - I have tried the following:

```
def finish 
  @a_hill = AHill.find(params[:hill_id])
  @finish_time = Result.create(:user_id => params[:user_id], :a_hill_id => params[:hill_id], :start_time =>@a_hill.start_time, :end_time=>Time.now, :total_time=>(Time.now.minus_with_coercion(@a_hill.start_time)).round)
  if @finish_time.save
    redirect_to(:action => "race", :id =>params[:hill_id] , :hill_id =>params[:hill_id])
  end
end
```

or to focus on the main part of that:

```
:total_time=>(Time.now.minus_with_coercion(@a_hill.start_time)).round
```

But i get the error

"TypeError in AHillsController#finish - can't convert String into an exact number"

:total_time is an integer :start_time and :end_time are datetimes

I'm pretty new to Rails so sorry if the answer is something very obvious and thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem you experience is indeed quite obvious :-) 
what you need is to transform @a_hill 's start_time to a Datetime object
try "@a_hill.start_time.to_datetime" or even better change the AHill object to have datetime objects in the start_time attribute.

Comment: From the error message, looks like @a_hill.start_time is a String instead of DateTime. Can you check what is the data-type of start_time?

Comment: Brilliant.. I was stupidly forgetting that I had pulled the start time in from a_hill (I double checked that the start_time and end_time in Result were datetime objects but didn't think it through much further- proper schoolboy error) .. @xlembouras I used .to_datetime to get it working(although i will change the object to have datetime objects as you suggest) so add your comment as an answer if you want the "Correct answer" points.. Thanks again both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to transform @a_hill 's start_time to a Datetime object try `@a_hill.start_time.to_datetime`
or even better change the AHill object to have datetime objects in the start_time attribute.